# IE7 put some extra right margin on super fish menu

Tags: internet-explorer, superfish

I have developed a business website that is based on Drupal. I integrated super fish menu on it however it puts some extra margin  when preview  IE6 and IE7. In IE8 and other browsers render it nicely  could you please  help me  fix that issue?

[Live website preview](http://www.kraiburg.com.tr/)

how it appear in IE7 and IE6

[image: on-ie6-ie7]
http://i51.tinypic.com/mrtydv.jpg

Answer (score 0):

Just try this,

```
#superfish .menu li li{ width:150px /*your wish but set fixed width*/}
```